# Creating A Scheduled Task on PHP Running Under IIS

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I'm fairly new to PHP. I need to run a function on my PHP site on a daily basis. I have seen posts on how to do this under Linux, but I'm running the PHP site on Windows Server 2012 under IIS. How can I create a PHP function and then run it at a certain time each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Task Scheduler on the server to run a batch file that runs the PHP script via command line at a regular interval, which i hope should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

*Run Cron Job on PHP Script, on localhost in Windows*

Create *script.bat* file with below Code

"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe" -f "C:\wamp\www\website\my_process.php"

Change wamp path to your iis path

Download & Install Zcron From Below Link

http://www.z-cron.com/download.html

Create New Task select your script.bat file and set timer

Comment: Thanks, but I can't install ZCron. This is not for personal use which is against the TOS of ZCron. Is there another way to do this?